# Sum numbers from one column when string in second column repeats

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to figure a way to sum the numbers of one column when a string from a second column repeats.

My file looks like this:

```
0.35    Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
0.21    Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
0.40    Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
0.27    Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
0.26    Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
0.20    Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
1.22    Scer|ChrI|ref|NC_001133.7|
0.08    Scer|ChrI|ref|NC_001133.7|
0.55    Scer|ChrVIII|ref|NC_001140.5|
0.07    Scer|ChrVIII|ref|NC_001140.5|
0.17    Scer|ChrVIII|ref|NC_001140.5|
```

And I'd like to have an output file that includes the name of the second column with the sum of the values of the first one for that particular string:

```
Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
1.69
Scer|ChrI|ref|NC_001133.7|
1.30
Scer|ChrVIII|ref|NC_001140.5|
0.79
```

I'm guessing It's doable with `awk` but I haven't been able to come out with the right answer nor found it in forums

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$NF]+=$1}END{for(x in a) printf "%s\n%4.2f\n",x,a[x]}' file
```

#### Output with your sample data:

```
$ awk '{a[$NF]+=$1}END{for(x in a) printf "%s\n%4.2f\n",x,a[x]}' file
Scer|ChrVIII|ref|NC_001140.5|
0.79
Scer|ChrIX|ref|NC_001141.1|
1.69
Scer|ChrI|ref|NC_001133.7|
1.30
```

#### If the output is needed in order:

```
awk 'seen==$2 { cnt+=$1 ; next }
     flag     { printf "%s\n%4.2f\n", seen,cnt ; flag=0 }
              { seen=$2 ; cnt=$1 ; flag=1 }
     END      { printf "%s\n%4.2f\n", seen,cnt}
' file
```

Comment: @Ramirous You're welcome. If you want the output in order then I have added another variant (though a little ugly).